# Perl function for summing increasing and decreasing amount of numbers

Tags: perl, scripting, sum, numbers, sequence

I am trying to create a Perl code to sum a list of numbers. Essentially I want to add up a column of numbers into groups of size which increase in increments of 1 up to 3 and then back again. Let's say the list of numbers are as follows:

> 0
> 0.2
> 0.4
> 0.01
> 0.5
> 0.7
> 0.03
> 0.55
> 0.3

What I want to do is increase and decrease the amount of numbers being added from 1  to 3 and back again, so first of all there would just be 0, then 0.2+0.4, then 0.01+0.5+0.7, then back down to 0.03+0.55 and finally just 0.3. The output would be a list of numbers equal to the sum of each of the following brackets.

> (0)
> (0.2+0.4)
> (0.01+0.5+0.7)
> (0.03+0.55)
> (0.3)

However, I'm a newbie to Perl and I'm really not sure how to approach this. Any advice would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: `0.2` is larger than `0`, so shouldn't the first set be `0, 0.2, 0.4`?

Comment: It's not the actual value of the numbers that matter, I ideally want this to work for different sets of numbers but in each case, keep the first value, add the next two together, then the next three, then the next two and finally print the last one

Comment: I see. . . . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficult part is determining how many elements are in the next group. To achieve this, we'd have to keep track of the size of the current group and whether the number is growing or shrinking.

Or we could use the following with an ascending number constrained to the array size using the modulus operator:

```perl
my @group_sizes = ( 1, 2, 3, 2, 1 );
```

Then, it simply becomes a question of tracking how many elements are remaining in the group.

```perl
my $sum;
my $group_sizes_idx = 0;
my $remaining = $group_sizes[$group_sizes_idx];
for my $num (@nums) {
   $sum += $num;

   if (--$remaining == 0) {
      say $sum;   # or C<< push @sums, $sum; >>.
      $sum = undef;
      $group_sizes_idx = ( $group_sizes_idx + 1 ) % @group_sizes
      $remaining = $group_sizes[$group_sizes_idx];
   }
}

# say $sum if defined($sum);   # Uncomment this to print the sum of a partial group.
```

---

`@group_sizes` can be built dynamically using

```perl
# -2 => 3 - 2 = 1
# -1 => 3 - 1 = 2
#  0 => 3 - 0 = 3
# +1 => 3 - 1 = 2
# +2 => 3 - 2 = 1

my @group_sizes = map { $n - abs($_) } -($n-1) .. ($n-1);
```

or

```perl
my @group_sizes = map { $n - abs($_ - $n + 1) } 0 .. $n*2 - 2;
```

This means you could use the following:

```perl
my $sum;
my $group_sizes_idx = 0;
my $remaining = 1;
for my $num (@nums) {
   $sum += $num;

   if (--$remaining == 0) {
      say $sum;   # or C<< push @sums, $sum; >>.
      $sum = undef;
      $group_sizes_idx = ( $group_sizes_idx + 1 ) % ( $n*2 - 1 );
      $remaining = $n - abs($group_sizes_idx - $n + 1);
   }
}

# say $sum if defined($sum);   # Uncomment this to print the sum of a partial group.
```